# PHP: xml-rpc and Turkish characters

Tags: xml-rpc

I am trying to post to my wordpress site by xml-rpc.

I have two problem about the turkish charcters.

1 - When i use one of theese characters **(Çç,Ğğ,Iı,Öö,Şş,Üü)** in the title sends a post to wordpress without title.?

2 - And when i use form same charcters in body content it sends in different form.

For example in body content i have "**Ankaralıyım**" an dit goes to wordpress as "**Ankaralýyým**".

Here is the code I use

```
 <?php
$title="Karaçay";
$body="Ankaralıyım";

$rpcurl="http://localhost/wp/xmlrpc.php";
$username="admin";
$password="pass";
$categories="try";

echo wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$categories,'');

function wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') 
{
    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $content = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$body,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>array($category)
    );
    $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params, array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
}

?>
```

I do not have any language problem when i add the post from wordpress.

How i will fix this?

And i have tried the same thing with different code and this time if there was any turkish character in the title or post I got this result
***Error while creating a new post-32700 : parse error. not well formed***
Second code is

```
<?php
        require("class-IXR.php");  
        $client = new IXR_Client('http://localhost/wp/xmlrpc.php');

        $USER = 'admin';
        $PASS = 'pass';

        $content['title'] = 'Test title '.mt_rand();
        $content['categories'] = array("NewCategory","Nothing");
        $content['description'] = '<p>Lorem ırmak ipsum dolor sit amet</p>';
        $content['custom_fields'] = array( array('key' => 'my_custom_fied','value'=>'yes') );
        $content['mt_keywords'] = array('foo','bar');

        if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost','', $USER,$PASS, $content, true))
        {
            die( 'Error while creating a new post' . $client->getErrorCode() ." : ". $client->getErrorMessage());  
        }
        $ID =  $client->getResponse();

        if($ID)
        {
            echo 'Post published with ID:#'.$ID;
        }

?>
```

This was the two different way to send post to wordpress by xml-rpc. But chacters different than english doesnt work. What i know there is utf-8 support of xml-rpc.

- I have already checked many sites and there was a solution with dead link.
  dead link is http://thr.gen.tr/php/xmlrpc-turkce-karakter-sorunu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `escaping->markup` parameter to `xmlrpc_encode_request`:

```
xmlrpc_encode_request('blogger.newPost',$params,
                            array('encoding'=>'UTF-8','escaping'=>'markup'));
```

Comment: This saved me 8 years later. Thanks!!

Comment: Seeing this late as well, wrote a more extensive answer over at _[Response from PHP xmlrpc_server_call_method has wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74757819/367456)_.

Answer (score 0):

That sure looks like some part of the pipeline isn't understanding or honoring that you want to use UTF-8 data.

Have you tried checking the raw data that is sent to the server, either via tools like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/), [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

You can also try enabling debugging in curl, with options [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTVERBOSE) and [CURLOPT_HEADER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHEADER):

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1)
```

Comment: Try to leave the `CURLOPT_HEADER` row out, it seems to confuse the parsing at some later step.

Comment: I have tried the right version of your codes but still i got the same error. Some letters are fine but Iı, Şş, Ğğ still not working.