# Response from PHP xmlrpc_server_call_method has wrong encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, xml-rpc

I use a PHP XMLRPC server to provide an interface to my blogging app (PDO/SQLite backend). Sending data to the database works and encoding stays intact, or at least strings with special characters such as umlauts (äöü) end up there correctly. But producing them from the database leads to problems and strings end up garbled.

**Example of my setup**

```php
function get_post($id) {
    
    // get the post from the database.
    $post = load_post($id);
    // if I output content here, all characters are intact, eg. "test with ümlaut"
    
    return $post;
}

// set up a server
$server = xmlrpc_server_create();
xmlrpc_server_register_method($server, 'metaWeblog.getPost', 'get_post');

// fake a request
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("metaWeblog.getPost", null, [
    'encoding' => 'utf-8'
]);

// call get_post()
$response = xmlrpc_server_call_method($server, $request, null, [
    'encoding' => 'utf-8'
]);

if($response) {
    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    echo($response); // has garbled umlauts
}
```

Produces the wrong string `test with Ã¼mlaut` instead of `test with ümlaut`

```xml
<member>
    <name>description</name>
    <value>
        <string>test with &#195;&#188;mlaut</string>
    </value>
</member>
```

Is there some way I can make this work without resorting to a different XMLRPC library? Ideally, prevent the escaping of special characters entirely, if possible.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works exactly like you ask for, only the `escaping` output option is missing, you want `markup` here (takes your Unicode UTF-8 string more or less verbatim) without any other value:

```php
$response = xmlrpc_server_call_method($server, $request, null, [
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'escaping' => 'markup',
]);
```

The `encoding` (as it will end up in the XML declaration) sets the document encoding declaration to `UTF-8`.

And with `markup` the plain UTF-8 string is taken and only XML markup characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, etc.) are escaped. This is contrary to the default which would also escape `non-ascii` and `non-print`(able) characters as numeric entities (`&#195;&#188`), those which are not helpful here as you *want* characters that are not specifically ASCII in their original encoding. UTF-8 albeit compatible with ASCII for the subset of the first 127 code-points, uses non-ASCII characters for flagging continuation bytes with the highest bit set, so those bytes are always higher than 127.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ...
    <member>
     <name>description</name>
     <value>
      <string>Äpfel wachsen überirdisch.</string>
     </value>
    </member>
  ...
```

**The `escaping` output-option**

You can find those options documented on the [`xmlrpc_encode_request(php)` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode-request.php#refsect1-function.xmlrpc-encode-request-parameters), as it is a bit brief, some discussion here in context of the answer:

The `escaping` *output-option* can take a string with a single value or an array with multiple string values.

The default is `['non-ascii', 'non-print', 'markup']`, a fourth value, `'cdata'`, is available as well:

1. `'non-ascii'`: every code-point higher than 127 (excluding) is escaped as *numeric entity* ([*XML: Character Reference*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref)); e.g. the UTF-8 `ü` (u-umlaut) as `&#195;&#188;`.
2. `'non-print'`: Every non-printable character is escaped as *numeric entity*. Compare RFC20. Not printable characters are all non-graphic characters, that is space (2/0, decimal 32) *is* printable and everything higher than 127 is *not* printable. Therefore, to preserve UTF-8 byte sequences, same as with `'non-ascii'`, it must **not** be set.
3. `'markup'`: suggested in the answer, the explanation above is likely falling short, for the details compare with [*XML: Markup*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-markup);
4. `'cdata'`: This puts strings into [*XML: CDATA Sections*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-cdsection). Not suggested in the answer but preserves UTF-8 as well and can be a fine escaping when the data contains strings that are XML, HTML or some other source code, like PHP, as well, as the response data then is easier to read by humans.

**Mind the NUL byte**

In XML-RPC, due to the fact it is XML based and likely implementation defined as well in the underlying C library, NUL bytes terminate a string.

If there is need to retain it, as XML itself does not have a character reference for it, encode it as base64 then (see RFC4648, a proposed standard, and [`xmlrpc_set_type(php)`](https://php.net/xmlrpc_set_type)).

Comment: Man, that actually did it! It's so weird because I swear I had `'escaping' => ['markup']` already and it didn't work. I left it out because I figured from the docs it was the default. What I didn't get at that moment is that *multiple* values are the default and only by explicitely declaring *one* value you deactivate `non-ascii` and `non-print`.
Upper- and lowercase `UTF-8` made no difference for me, but I get why you mentioned it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for commenting. I think the answer also didn't make that really visible so I improved it a bit listing all the options. The casing in UTF-8 may not make a difference because if it is unknown for a parser, there is often the fall-back to UTF-8. IMHO it's good style, also reduced the comment on it.